# eglfs - multiple windows

Tags: linux, qt, opengl-es-2.0, qtquick2

Working on a embedded linux device with touch screen. Compiled `Qt` with `eglfs` support and using `tslib` for the touch screen. All good up until here. Now, I need to add a virtual keyboard. I've this keyboard as `platforminputcontextplugin` which works very well on my development linux machine. How can this be done on the embedded device? `eglfs` is forcing the top window (main window) to full screen and the keyboard is struck behind this window.

What are the options available to me? we need `eglfs` as it supports `OpenGL ES` which in turn used by `Qt Quick` (`QML`).

Comment: What virtual keyboard are you using? The one included in the Qt Commercial version is basically just a QML object and you can make it pop up or do whatever you want with it within the single eglfs window, just like you would any other QML widget. There is an open-source reimplementation of this keyboard that I used in my project and it works fine with single-window eglfs: https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/QtFreeVirtualKeyboard

Comment: Did u managed to make it work? I'm asking the same too

Comment: @LiLou_ I've followed the same example as suggested by _ScottG_. Used https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/QtFreeVirtualKeyboard as an example and created my own version. Thanks.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror Sorry but isn't that project u linked me already an implementation? And how do u actually use it? I have git cloned `QtFreeVirtualKeyboard` and built it for desktop. I put the generated file `libfreevirtualkeyboardplugin.so` on my plugins folder and at the end I tell my application to use it with this sentence: `qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("freevirtualkeyboard"));`. But the virtual keyboard doesn't pop-up when I focus on a input field. The output it does: `VirtualKeyboardInputContext::setFocusObject
"InputMethodHints: 0"
CDeclarativeInputEngine::setInputMode  0`

Comment: @LiLou_ are you using `Qwidget`s or `QML`?

Comment: @ramtheconqueror I'm testing with a qt example ("gallery") that uses quickcontrols2, so QML. Would be good if it can be used with Qwdigets too.

Comment: @LiLou_ have you also copied QML files into the QML plugins path? If you see `MainContainer.qml` in example included, you can find the import statement to import the keyboard. Thanks.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror Sry, so I needed to do a `make install` after building instead of copying files manually. Now it works ;)

Comment: So it only works with QML applications :S